# Office JS Api, Word, preview part of document in taskpane

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm looking for a solution for this:

On the task pane I'd like to show the image of the first page of the document.

What I have tried so far:
Office.document.getFileAsync() -> get it as PDF -> get slice as base64, load base64 in iframe like

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,"+base64pdf>
```

but it only shows an empty frame without any error or warning.
The interesting part is, that if I copy the iframe url and open it in a browser, it works as intented, only in the taskpane I get an empty frame.

An other option would be that I use an img tag, but how can I get the word document as an image?

Comment: For the sake of example, let's say that the word document has only 1 page. 
My problem is that I don't know how to show the pdf in the taskpane, or how to convert pdf into an image

Comment: @KJ, I don't think I know what is the difference between what I did and what you just said.
The src of the iframe is not too long, because otherwise it wouldn't work in the browser I assume?
Even copy pasting the same working iframe into the officejs code won't work